# background color not appearing behind logo css

Tags: html, css, svg

i want to remove the white space behind the logo because the background color is not covering it. i tried using paint to crop the logo but its not neat
i tried putting background color behind image not working
i want this output
[image]

my output:

[image]

image url:
https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2Fc%2Fc0%2FCOMSATS_new_logo.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fcommons.wikimedia.org%2Fwiki%2FFile%3ACOMSATS_new_logo.jpg&tbnid=xspWDo9unvGAWM&vet=12ahUKEwj3586ygbj2AhVS8eAKHT2sBSwQMygAegUIARC4AQ..i&docid=Nuuz_7AWjCW4JM&w=770&h=769&q=comsats%20round%20logo&ved=2ahUKEwj3586ygbj2AhVS8eAKHT2sBSwQMygAegUIARC4AQ

Comment: Your image is a .jpg! jps files have no alpha (opacity) channel!

Comment: because of you are using "JPG" images. it is not transparent background. you have to use "PNG" image for or Using this website you can easily remove background from the image .  https://www.remove.bg/upload

Answer (score 1):

Since your logo has a simple circular shape, you could also use a css [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)

```css
body{
background:#ccc;  
}

.logo-round{
  width:20%;
  height:auto;
  clip-path: circle(42%);
}
```

```html
<img class="logo-round" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c0/COMSATS_new_logo.jpg/600px-COMSATS_new_logo.jpg" />
```

```
 clip-path: circle(42%);
```

The right percentage value depends on the whitespace/background surrounding the logo – in this case 42% should work pretty fine.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, you can't add opacity to a JPG image. You'll need to convert this to a PNG.